# Instance resolution in Idris

Tags: idris

Can someone tell me why this

```
works : WriterT w (ReaderT r Identity) _ -> ReaderT r Identity w
works = execWriterT
```

but this

```
doesnt : WriterT w (Reader r) _ -> Reader r w
doesnt = execWriterT
```

I get the error

```
Can't find implementation for Functor (Reader r)
```

But since the definition of `Reader r a` is `ReaderT r Identity a` we can see that `works` and `doesnt` are definitionally the same. I'm thinking this is just a bug with the instance resolution algorithm. What gives?

I'm totally new to Idris, I'm not sure if I can supply the instance argument explicitly somehow.

For completenes the definition of `execWriterT` is:

```
execWriterT : Functor m => WriterT w m a -> m w
execWriterT = (map snd) . runWriterT
```

Environment information:

```
> uname -rov                       
4.15.0-29-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 17 15:39:52 UTC 2018 GNU/Linux
> idris --version
1.3.0-git:61cf812e
```

EDIT: Also for Idris version `1.3.0-git:713e485f` (`master` as of the time of writing)

Answer (score 1):

It is a library bug, really. `Reader` is defined by

```
Reader r a = ReaderT r Identity a
```

Notice `a` is an argument to `Reader`. This eta-contracts to

```
Reader r = ReaderT r Identity
```

but these definitions are not equivalent. (Or rather: they are extensionally equivalent (same behavior), but not intensionally (same definition).)

The reason `doesnt` doesn't work is because `Reader r` does not reduce. `Reader` is defined with two arguments, and `Reader r` only applies one argument. It is not fully saturated, therefore it will not simplify. Idris simply doesn't know that `Reader r` is related to `ReaderT r Identity` until you apply one more argument. This makes instance resolution break down, because the instance is for `ReaderT r f`, not `Reader r` (and you *can't* write a (useful) instance for `Reader r`, because `Reader` is not a data type).

This works:

```
Reader' : Type -> Type -> Type
Reader' r = ReaderT r Identity

doesnt : WriterT w (Reader' r) _ -> Reader' r w
doesnt = execWriterT
```

Though the more correct thing would be to [submit a PR](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev).

Comment: I don't understand why it shouldn't be able to see that `Reader r` is "related" to `ReaderT r Identity`. I your note about extensionality, but if you just reduce `Reader r` one step then you get to `ReaderT r Identity`. Even though it's under a lambda, aren't they still definitionally equal? That said I tried with your suggested patch to `Control.Monad.Reader` but I get the same error... And doesn't `Reader r` have the type `Type -> Type`, so surely it's still a type.

Comment: @fredefox [Works for me...](https://tryidris.herokuapp.com/compile#bW9kdWxlIE1haW4KCmltcG9ydCBDb250cm9sLk1vbmFkLklkZW50aXR5CmltcG9ydCBDb250cm9sLk1vbmFkLlJlYWRlcgppbXBvcnQgQ29udHJvbC5Nb25hZC5Xcml0ZXIKClJlYWRlcicgOiBUeXBlIC0+IFR5cGUgLT4gVHlwZQpSZWFkZXInIHIgPSBSZWFkZXJUIHIgSWRlbnRpdHkKCmV4ZWNXcml0ZXJUIDogRnVuY3RvciBmID0+IFdyaXRlclQgdyBmIHIgLT4gZiB3CmV4ZWNXcml0ZXJUID0gbWFwIHNuZCAuIHJ1bldyaXRlclQKCmRvZXNudCA6IFdyaXRlclQgdyAoUmVhZGVyJyByKSBfIC0+IFJlYWRlcicgciB3CmRvZXNudCA9IGV4ZWNXcml0ZXJUCgptYWluIDogSlNfSU8gKCkKbWFpbiA9IFt8ICgpIHxd)

Comment: @fredefox Now that that link isn’t taking up my characters: sure, it’s just one eta-contraction, but that’s one eta-contraction too many. You can prove the extensional, propositional equality `(r : Type) -> Reader r = ReaderT r Identity`, but I think that’s it, and it’s not definitional.